# C# perform bulk delete on 50000 and more records

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, bulk

I have an issue where I have a piece of code like following:

```
  var inPast = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-30);
    DBRetry.Do(() => EFBatchOperation.For(ctx, ctx.Transactions).Where(t =>  t.TransactionDate <= inPast).Delete(), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
```

The `DBRetry` function simply repeats the operation every 2 seconds if an timeout or deadlock occurs...

Now the problem here is that my `Transactions` table contains 100 million+ records...

As you can see I'm trying to delete all records that are older than 30 days... However this doesn't works since I'm constantly getting timeout like following:

> Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to
>   completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

The column `TransactionDate` is indexed, and it is a non-unique & non clustered index, but this doesn't seems to help... The library that I'm using to perform bulk delete is this one:

```
https://github.com/MikaelEliasson/EntityFramework.Utilities
```

Does anyone knows a more efficient solution or how I could solve this issue?

Comment: Maybe a relational database isn't the answer if this is the use case.

Comment: If you delete the rows with direct sql command, how long does it take?

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer I can't change the entire database structure because of that... I need some sort of solution :/

Comment: @AntonínLejsek even longer =/

Comment: If you are getting timeouts it's because your timeout limit is too low for the amount if time it takes to finish the query on the server side. Simply increase your timeout limit in the connection string when performing that query.

Comment: @User987 it is impossible that the sql command takes longer than the EF query. EF is automatically at least a couple milliseconds longer. If not then your query is not optimized.

Comment: That is unlikely, as EF uses SQL too, anyway, how long in "longer"? Do you have any triggers on the table? How many indexes do you have on the table? Does any other table have FK referencing this table and is it covered by index?

Comment: Deleting items one at a time takes time.  It may be better to use a stored procedure to do the deleting.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer 50K rows is a tiny tiny amount. RDBMSs work with multiple TBs and billions of rows per database. The problem is the design, not the database. If you use an ORM instead of SQL to do set- and batch- based work, it will slow you down. Deleting 50K root objects in a document DB won't be fast either. If they *aren't* root ...

Comment: @User987 if you wanted to delete or move a *lot* of rows, you could do so in no time at all by [partitioning the data by date](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/partitions/create-partitioned-tables-and-indexes?view=sql-server-2017) and [partition switching](https://sqlsunday.com/2014/08/24/reloading-fact-tables-with-zero-downtime/). Moving a partition from one table to another is just a metadata operation and almost instantaneous. Even if it contains 1M rows

Comment: One more question, if you are the only user of the database, does it take the same time?

Comment: There are lots of options to solve this. Using entity framework is nearly always inefficient for batch opertations. Are you using SQL server? You could create a database scheduled job that will run on a certain interval and delete the unwanted rows https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/create-a-job?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do some things to mitigate this problem;

1) Entity Framework tends to have a requirement that records/objects are loaded into memory first before allowing you to delete them, which can be a big performance hit in itself.

It could be better to run some custom SQL for this operation instead

2) Create indexes within the database table for the field transaction date

Imagine what a database has to do within a large table to run a select->where query, given a large enough record set it has to scan through all of them to determine which records you need.  Adding indexes to this table helps give the database clues to which fields you query to most and lets the database optimise these operations for you.

3) Run the query more often than 30 days

Assuming this is a regular house keeping operation, running it more often than 30 days would keep the number of rows within the database table to a minimum.  In some databases you can even add schedules, so there's no need to include this in the code.

4) Delete the records in batches

If you have to use Entity Framework for this, you can select the rows you wish to delete in batches of X amount;  this help distribute the load on the database, just in case the operation can take many minutes to perform.

Answer (score 1):

You could try increasing the command timeout for your Db context:

(Originally at [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6fe91a64-0208-4ab8-8667-d061af340994/ef-41-dbcontext-commandtimeout?forum=adodotnetentityframework))

```
public class YourContext : DbContext
{
  public YourContext()
    : base("YourConnectionString")
 {
    // Get the ObjectContext related to this DbContext
    var objectContext = (this as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext;

    // Sets the command timeout for all the commands
    objectContext.CommandTimeout = 120;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think indexes are the solution and may be the problem.
IF a table has indexes on several columns then the delete might be locking the records to update the indexes. This is costly and takes time try breaking it up. Get the list of ID's for the records and then delete them in batches of say 10,000

Answer (score 0):

Since it is likely to take more than 2 seconds to delete 50K rows, do it in much smaller chunks; say 1000.

Also, do not "do it every 2 seconds"; instead "do it continually".  That is, after finishing with one batch, do the next batch.  Optionally pause briefly between batches.  Doing the delete on a fixed schedule can lead to stumbling over multiple copies running simultaneously.

This discusses several techniques:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig

Note that that link suggests `PARTITION BY RANGE(TO_DAYS())` as the optimal way to do big deletes.  Daily (or weekly) partitions would be advised.

Answer (score 0):

```
DbContext.Database.CommandTimeout = 0; // set unlimited timeout
```

Or set it to 0 in config file

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout?view=netframework-4.7.2